# If statment on ng-click?

Tags: angularjs

I need to call function on ng-click but only if   `$scope.currentActiveMenu = 1;`.
How can i do that?

```
ng-click="GetAllTickets(0,25) = currnetActiveMenu==1">
```

or something like that?

Comment: You must keep your view as clean as possible, that is the baseline of any framework like Angular itself. And try to move this whole logic to controller.

Comment: `currnetActiveMenu` should probably be `currentActiveMenu` (invert `n` and `e`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't put any Condition Expression in Template, do it in the Controller.

```
ng-click="checkCurrentActiveMenu(currentActiveMenu)">
```

Controller :

```
$scope.checkCurrentActiveMenu = function(value) {
    if (value == 1) {
       GetAllTickets(0,25);
    }
}
```

If you really need this in the template, you can use this (if the first condition isn't true, the second one will not be called):

```
ng-click="currentActiveMenu==1 && GetAllTickets(0,25)">
```

Comment: This is a better approach. Its always good not to have too many expression on template.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
ng-click="currnetActiveMenu === 1 && GetAllTickets(0,25)"
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a function in your controller:

```
ng-click="GetAllTicketsForMenu(0,25, currnetActiveMenu)">
```

in your controller:

```
$scope.GetAllTicketsForMenu = function(val1,val2, currnetActiveMenu){
    if(currnetActiveMenu === 1){
      $scope.GetAllTickets(val1,val2);
    }
};
```

You could also try a ternary:

```
ng-click="currnetActiveMenu==1 ? GetAllTickets(0,25) : null ">
```